# How to set maxSavePostSize in Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

To integrate a software we required to set the `maxSavePostSize`. Where can I do it? I found out that there is a folder `conf` with several files, but where exactly do I have to put that setting?

Answer (score 1):

`maxSavePostSize` is an attribute of the `Connector` element in the file `server.xml`. You may want to set it to `"0"` to disable saving if you know that the client will send the POST request again after authentication.

See corresponding documentation, e.g. Tomcat 8.5:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes